# AndroidSDK Apk creation vs Ionic Cordova prod build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am new to Ionic and android app development, and i need your help to clarify my basic questions

I am using ionic capacitor for creating APP, and further using androidSDK for building apk. When i go to ionic website , it says ionic cordova build release to create apks.

Why do i need to use ionic cordova platform for building ? if am i expected to add cordova as integration?  iF cordova will go away soon and Capacitor is next , then why we have to use cordova .

Comment: Why am i asked to add cordova as integration

Comment: Because if you want to build an application you need cordova. Cordova is a platform used to build hybrid mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

`Ionic` is a framework which allows you to use Angular/Vue/React to build web files. (HTML/JS/CSS).

To make this web code runnable as a mobile application on multiple platforms, `Ionic` relies on `cordova`. `cordova` is a framework which generates native projects (Xcode for iOS, Android studio for android, and many others). These native builds embed and run the web code generated with Ionic. To make it simple, `Ionic` is a web development framework, and `cordova` helps you create a native app with a webview, which runs the web project made with `Ionic`.

But in 2018, `Ionic` announced `Capacitor`, a new framework they created, and that aims to replace `cordova` in `Ionic` projects.

So once you want to build your Ionic project as a mobile application, you will have the choice to rely on `cordova` or on `capacitor`.

To build your Ionic project with capacitor, you can use :

```
ionic capacitor build platform
```

Where platform can be, for example, `ios` or `android`

This single command runs all the below commands, which may help to understand how capacitor works :

1. `npm run build` builds/prepares/minifies your web files into the `www` directory
2. `npx cap copy` once your web code is built, it is copied into each native project (android and ios directories)
3. If you are building for android, it will run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` from `android` folder. If you are building for ios, it will run an `xcodebuild` from `ios` folder

Here are some resources :

- https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/building-your-app
- https://ionic.io/resources/articles/capacitor-vs-cordova-modern-hybrid-app-development

Comment: Is there any difference if i just use capacitor and generate the apk using  ionic capacitor build android --prod --release   vs ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Comment: This will output the same apk. `capacitor` and `cordova` are 2 different tools with the same purpose.

Comment: If it is that so, why the codepush does not work integrated to Capacitor, Do you have any sample project implementing Ionic (Capacitor and Codepush appcenter)

Comment: Have you read how to install and use cordova plugins with capacitor ? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins